# How could I assign values to c++ vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I know that I can initialize a vector like this:

```
vector<int> v{1,3,4,6};
```

However, when I define a class which contains a vector, I cannot initialize it in the position that I declare it, like this:

```
class C {
  public: 
    vector<int> v; 
    C();
};
```

Thus I need to initialize it in the construction function. The following code works, but is not clean:

```
C::C() {
    v.resize(4); 
    v[0]=1; 
    v[1]=3; 
    v[2]=4; 
    v[3]=6;
}
```

How could I initialize it neatly and directly like `vector<int> v{1,3,4,6};` rather than assign values one by one ?

Edit: 
Maybe I have not make my situation clear. The value of {1,3,4 6} may not be predefined values, they would depend on some logic and conditions: `if(condition_a) {v[0] = 0; v[1]=3; ...} else {v[0]=4;v[0]=8;...}`. Thus I have to deal with some other things to know how to initialize this vector, so I cannot use initialization list as suggested in some answers. Any advice please?

Comment: If `condition_a` is determined by the caller (the function that creates the instance of `C`) then your constructor should accept an initialiser list, and the caller should pass it.    If `condition_a` is determined within the class based on information not supplied to the constructor (e.g. via a static) then your design is flawed.   A class that can be constructed twice, with the same constructor arguments, and produce two logically different objects (with different contents) is a software bug waiting to be found - probably by the end user, and probably really hard for the developer to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :

```
#include <vector>
class C {
   std::vector<int> v;
public :
   C() {
      if(...)
         v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
      else
         v = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
      //and other statement
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: I had this in mind, but then you didn't define what conditions they would be based upon. This would work, provided your conditions are not related to the vector. (Otherwise you'll need to initialize it with some values first!)

Answer (score 7):

Following would work:

```cpp
C::C()
    : v{ 1, 3, 4, 6 }
{}
```

**Note** that in the code above you are passing the `std::initializer_list` to the `std::vector`'s constructor.

Answer (score 5):

You can initialize it in member initializer list like

```
class C{
public: 
    vector<int> v; 
    C() : v {1,3,4,6} {}
};
```

Or use [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) like

```
class C{
public: 
    vector<int> v {1,3,4,6};
    C() {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an initializer list for the constructor.

Pertaining to conditional initialization as per your edited question, just initialize the vector contents to 0 and then apply whatever condition(s) you require and initialize specific values accordingly:

```cpp
class C 
{
  public:
    vector<int> v;
    C() : v{0,0,0,0}
    {   if(v.size()==4) // your condition
          v[0]=1;
    }
};
```